# MS SQL Query Including omitted rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Here is my over-simplified database structure;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names](
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Names] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scores](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Score] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'f')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'g')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'h')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'j')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Names] ([Name]) VALUES (N'k')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Scores] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Scores] ([id], [Name], [Score]) VALUES (1, N'a', 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Scores] ([id], [Name], [Score]) VALUES (2, N'b', 15)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Scores] ([id], [Name], [Score]) VALUES (3, N'f', 12)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Scores] ([id], [Name], [Score]) VALUES (4, N'k', 3)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Scores] OFF
GO
```

I am trying to get those names who have score less than 12, yet print other names as well with null or empty data as score. you may view the desired output in the following picture:

[image: desired output]

I achieved my goal using this query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Names.Name, id, Score FROM Names
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores
    ON Names.Name = Scores.Name
    WHERE Scores.Score < 12
)

SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT Name , Null , Null
FROM Names
WHERE Names.name NOT IN 
    (SELECT Name FROM cte)
ORDER BY name
```

But unfortunately, I have restriction of not using CTE since the actual query (non-simplified version) uses CTE and nested CTE is not supported.

Can you provide another way to do this?

**Performance concerns:** the actual query (which I am mimicking here using a cte) has over 1 million rows and already joins over 10 tables and benefit from aggregates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You just need to put the condition in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT n.Name, s.id, s.Score 
FROM Names n
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores s
      ON n.Name = s.Name 
         AND s.score < 12
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef95c/1).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you need this;

```
SELECT Names.Name, id, Score FROM Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores
ON Names.Name = Scores.Name
WHERE Scores.Score < 12
Or scores.score is null
```

EDIT
John woo pointed out this isn't correct... Another way to get there correct result set (I think) is;

```
SELECT Names.Name, id,
Case when Score <12 or score is null
    Then null
 Else score end as score
 FROM Names
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores
 ON Names.Name = Scores.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT n.Name,CASE WHEN s.Score < 12 THEN Score
             ELSE NULL 
   FROM dbo.Names n
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Scores s
   ON n.Name=s.Name;
```

As far of my understanding